# Windows SMTP server for email api

Tags: windows, email, daemon

I'm architecting a web service where users can update, for example, a blog by sending an email. What's a good email server for Windows for this? Any other advice / examples appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server has built in SMTP, if it meets your needs.

Comment: Then what would you recommend for polling it? Connecting just via pop3?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want SMTP like your title says or do you want a POP3 mailbox server?  They are two different things.